# align five divs equally next to each other

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm even finding it difficult to phrase my question right so bear with me here please.

I have one div that serves as the main container of my page. Inside that div I would like to have five other divs which have equal size and equal margins. However when I calculate everything right, the fifth div always jumps to the next line.

I hope this makes sense. This is my code:

CSS and HTML as follows

```css
    #content {
     position: absolute;
     width: 1000px;
     height: 500px;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     margin-left: -500px;
     margin-top: -250px;
     border: 2px solid #f9423a;
     border-radius: 10px;
     background-color: #3eb1c8;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .bookmark {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 15%;
     height: 20%;
     margin-left: 2%;
     margin-right: 2%;
     margin-top: 2.5%;
     border: 1px solid #f9423a;
     border-radius: 10px;
     background-color: #f9423a;
    }
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
  <div class="bookmark"></div>
</div>
```

Note that I'm just working with color-filled divs to see if it's working.

As you can see it almost works, the online thing that bothers me is that there's a bit more margin on the right than there is on the left. I would like to have equal margins between the sides and the outer elements, and between the inner elements of course.

I hope someone understands my question!

Comment: How many divs you want in a row?

Comment: I'd like five divs per row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
check this example, if this is what you wanted
```

Here i have removed the right margin and increased the bookmark div with to 17%

```
.bookmark {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 17%;
    height: 20%;
    margin-left: 2%;    
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    border: 1px solid #f9423a;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f9423a;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0gkfp7zr/

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using: `display: inline-block` which reads the white space between your divs on your HTML code as a literal white space, like putting a space between words, that breaks the layout.

Try changing your sintax like this:

```
<div>content</div><div>
content2</div><div>
content3</div><div>
content4</div><div>
content5</div>
```

Then, for the CSS you could use calc(); to add borders, that would ruin your layout too.
Like this:

```
div {
    width: calc(20% - 4px);//20*5 = 100 - 2px on each side each time
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/fgxfmk75/1/)

```css
body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

div {    
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(20% - 4px); 
    /*20*5 = 100 - 2px on each side each time*/
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>content1</div><div>
content2</div><div>
content3</div><div>
content4</div><div>
content5</div>
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to do the trick. is there another way around, like, using something else than display: inline-block?

Comment: You can do it with floats, its the more accepted way, but this DOES the trick for sure, I will upload a fiddle for you

Comment: JSFiddle added, check it out

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make me a fiddle, but this doesn't solve my problem. I can get my page to look like the fiddle, but I'd like to have equal maximum margins between the divs and no matter how I calculate the margins, there's always something wrong. When my margin is too small the margins aren't equal, and when my margin is the right calculated size the fifth div jumps to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Aramil's answer is good and correct correct. There is no "nice" way to deal with this. Different people have different methods, but they are all a bit hackish. The way I prefer to do it is with comments as follows:

```
<div class="bookmark"></div><!--
--><div class="bookmark"></div><!--
--><div class="bookmark"></div><!--
--><div class="bookmark"></div><!--
--><div class="bookmark"></div>
```

Basically you don't want any white space between one closing div and the next opening div. Sometimes if my content is short enough I will put them all together on one line as you see below, but it makes it much harder to read.

```
<div class="bookmark"></div><div class="bookmark"></div><div class="bookmark"></div><div class="bookmark"></div><div class="bookmark"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to .bookmark

float:left and the add .8 to the width of bookmark, your computation is not equal because in 1 bookmark div you have 15% plus the margin-left and right which is 4%, total of 1 div is 19 x 5 = 95 so I added .8 to fill the remaining white spaces. 19.8 x 5 = 99

```
.bookmark {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15.8%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  border: 1px solid #f9423a;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f9423a;
  float: left;
}
```